# Reading coils in modbus protocol

Tags: c#, modbus

I am doing a project in modbus, i framed the request for reading coils in TCP,but i dont know how to do it for serialport can anyone help to frame this.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you're using C#. In this case, I suggest you to use the [nmodbus](http://code.google.com/p/nmodbus/) library.
It's open source and allows you to perform any Modbus operation via both TCP and serial protocol.